# Struts Jquery Select tag sometimes not get data. (<sj:select />)

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I use

```
<sj:select />
```

some times it get data. sometimes it will not, then I need to refresh the page for populate select box.
Please help me...

for populating category

```
<s:url var="categoryUrl" action="returnTrainings"/>
<sj:select
      href="%{categoryUrl}"
      id="category" cssClass="employeeinput"
      onChangeTopics="reloadsecondlist"
      onAlwaysTopics="reloadsecondlist"
      name="categoryNameForTraining"
      list="distinctCategory"
      headerKey="0"
      headerValue="Select a Category"/>
```

for populating training

```
<sj:select
    href="%{categoryUrl}"
    id="selectWithReloadTopic" cssClass="employeeinput"
    formIds="TrainList"
    reloadTopics="reloadsecondlist"
    name="traininglist.hcmoTrainingListId" list="selectedtrainingNames"
    listKey="hcmoTrainingListId" 
    listValue="trainingName"
    headerKey="0"
    headerValue="Select a Training"/>
```

Comment: Sure, wait, [I'm consulting my CookBook](http://www.caak.mn/downloads/images15/201207/bibli-stopped/bibliya-0004.jpg). Sometimes it works. Sometimes not.